# King's haircut, every hair the same length?

Tags: talmud-gemara, malchut-royalty, haircuts

I think I remember seeing somewhere in the Talmud that the King's haircut entailed that each hair should be exactly the same length.

Am I mistaken, or does anyone know the source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sanhedrin 22b discusses the haircut of a *Kohen Gadol*, which should be '*rosho shel zeh b'tzad ikaro shel zeh*'. (I'm not translating as I don't fully understand what this means.)

I am unaware of any references in the Talmud to a *King's* haircut.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Joel! Thanks for the answer.

Comment: translatio. for that is "The end of one hair reaches to the root of the next hair."

Comment: But does that necessarily mean each hair is of the same length (as mentioned in the question)? Presumably, one could have hairs of different lengths but still comply with "The end of one hair reaches to the root of the next hair", depending on how the roots are positioned on the head.

Answer (score 0):

The every hair being the same length might be the haircut of a כהן גדול, as referenced in Joel's answer, from Sanhedrin 22b. 
That gemara also discusses a King's haircut and says that he has a haircut **every day** in order that he always look respectable, though the gemara does not mention the length of that haircut.